# Ajax Dropdown | Cypress | Query

Tags: cypress, dropdown

[image: Display dropdowns]

**Use Case**

We need to select a table from drop down list, based on tables it will display columns available I the table. After we select columns, it will generate a query in text box. Once query generated, we conclude the action and application will move to next page where it will fetch the data based on query which is generated.

We have more than 100 tables in our database. For looping through each row in drop down I use each loop as below

```javascript
cy.get( 'div[id*="downshift-1-item"]' ).each( ($el,index,$list)=>{
  cy.get("#downshift-1-item-"+ index).click()
  cy.get('.TreeSelect-module_floatLeft__2gnXf').click()
  cy.get('.input.full-width').then(function(elMessage){
    const sqlQuery = elMessage.val();
    cy.get('.Multiline_multilineInput_2Bmo4').type(sqlQuery)
  }); // End cy.get('.input.full-width')
});
```

But my Loop terminated after the 23rd row.

**Possible Reason**

Only first 23 rows are visible in to DOM when we select the dropdown, once we scroll down few rows added in DOM and first few rows gets removed.

```javascript
cy.log($list) // Results in 23
```

Query: How to handle this scenario?

Comment: It's hard to see how the table is constructed without a sample html. Otherwise, it would be a guessing game.

Comment: Added the image in the original post

Answer (score 0):

The "Cypress-way" of doing this is to put all the options in a fixture and loop through them.

```js
// cypress/fixtures/my-options.json
[
  "APPROVAL_LEVEL",
  "APPROVAL_LIST",
  ...
]
```

```js
cy.fixture('my-options').then(options => {
  cy.wrap(options).each((options, index) => {
    cy.get("#downshift-1-item-"+ index).click()
    cy.log(option)
    ...
  })
})
```

If you try to screen-scrape the options from the virtual select, the test code will be much more complicated and you will not have tested any more deeply.